# R programming: How to create several data.frames in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

a very simple question.
I'm trying to create different data frames in this for loop:

`for (i in seq_along(country_code)) {
                        UrlRoot<-"http://climatedataapi.worldbank.org/climateweb/rest/v1/country/cru/tas/month/"
                        fileUrl <- paste(UrlRoot,country_code[i],sep = "")
                        get_tas <- fromJSON(fileUrl)
                        climate_data <- rbind(climate_data,get_tas)`

My aim is create a data frame per country containing the climate data I can get from the API. Like:

```
AWA

month data

0       21

1       21.3

...     .... 

AFG

0       19.5

1       22.4

...     ....
```

But I cannot divide the data of a country from the others storing them in different data frame. This is what I get:

```
     month        data
1       0 26.49174100
2       1 26.67431300
3       2 27.21926500
4       3 27.64128500
5       4 28.24770500
6       5 28.43945000
7       6 28.56605500
8       7 28.79541400
9       8 28.83853100
10      9 28.36330200
11     10 27.78715500
12     11 27.09082600
13      0  0.09617378
14      1  2.24567600
15      2  7.38042300
16      3 13.16199500
17      4 18.25324400
18      5 23.07769600
19      6 25.17552200
20      7 23.81981300
```

Any hint? thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a column to `climate_data` with the country name (`climate_data$country <- i`) and then query the respective country.

Or use `assign(i, climate_data)`, which assigns the value of `climate_data` to a variable that has the name of `i`.